# Exercise measure theory: properties of a function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ ($n\geq 2$) a bounded domain. Let $u \in L^{1}(\Omega)$.
For each number $c >0$ define $A_c :=\{ x \in \Omega; u(x) > c\}$. Define

$$ f(k) := \int_{A_k} (u(x)-k) dx$$.

I am reading  a book and the author says that

$$f(k) = \int_{k}^{+\infty} |A_t| dt  \ \ \ (*)$$

and

$$ - f^{'}(k) = |A_k|\ \ \ \ (**)$$.

I have no idea of how to prove these two identities. Someone could help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formula $(\ast)$ is a change of the order of integration in some double integral, as explained several times on the site: start from $$u(x)-k=\int_k^\infty\mathbf 1_{t<u(x)}dt,$$ for every $u(x)>k$ and integrate this on $A_k$. Exchanging the order of the integrals, one gets $$\int_{A_k}(u(x)-k)dx=\int_k^{\infty}\int_{A_k}\mathbf 1_{t<u(x)}dxdt=\int_k^{\infty}\int_{A_t}dxdt=\int_k^{\infty}|A_t|\,dt.$$ Formula $(\ast\ast)$ is a simple consequence of the derivation of an integral whose bounds depend on a parameter.

Comment: Please Did , could you explain a justificative of  your first identity or point me where I can find a proof? thanks for your attention

Comment: Did you try to *compute* the integral on the RHS. Since the function to be integrated is always zero or one, the task should not be *that* difficult...

Comment: @Did. Unfortunately I am not seeing how to verify your first indentity ... I am sorry ...

Comment: ?? For every $\ell>k$, $$\int_k^\infty\mathbf 1_{t<\ell}dt=\int_k^\ell 1\cdot dt+\int_\ell^\infty 0\cdot dt=\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks Did. I dont know how I did not see this. Sorry and thanks for your attention

Answer (score -1):

That depends a bit on which definition of integrals you're using. I take the liberty to use the simplest for the purpose - sloppily expressed the area (or measure) of the region under the graph (and taking it negative if below the x-axis).

The (*) should be rather straight forward using this definition as it's basically the same set we're measuring. You have to do the outer-inner measurement construct first to see this though.

The (**) follows from that we can use the estimate $f(k+h)-f(k)$ to be between $|h||A_k|$ and $|h||A_{k+h}|$.

If you're not using this definition it will be required to prove that $\int f(x)dx = |P|-|N|$ where $P = \{x, y: 0\le y\le f(x)\}$ and $N=\{x, y: f(x)\le y \le 0\}$.

Comment: "The (*) should be rather straight forward using this definition as it's basically the same set we're measuring." No idea what you mean here. Can you explain?

Comment: "You have to do the outer-inner measurement construct first" What?

Comment: @Did $\inf\{\sum\mu(I_k)\}$ as described in the wikipedia article on the Lebesgue measure for example. My intention was not to solve his exercise, but to give him hints.

Comment: How do these apply? Do they apply?

Comment: They apply because they are part of the definition of the integral. Have you tried to apply them? Did you run into any particular problem?

Comment: Sure, the "particular problem" anybody trying to apply these "hints" run into is that they do not help to solve the problem. Do you understand the principles this site is based upon?

Comment: I think I know the principles. My point is that for a question like this (help with an exercise) the "proper" answer is hints to help them solve the problem themselves. Don't you agree, or do you mean that I should post the complete solution to the problem?

Comment: Offtopic (and a little more than naively so). The only problem you should be interested in is: *Do these so-called hints actually help to solve THIS problem?* I might have missed some subtlety but at present, my answer to that is "No, they cannot help". Please show me I am wrong.